# How to remove a page in RadPageView?

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik

How can I remove on runtime a page in a RadPageView?

```
this.pvMyPageView.Pages["pvpMyPageViewPage"].Remove();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RadPageViewPage pageToRemove = this.radPageView1.Pages["pvpMyPageViewPage"];
this.radPageView1.Pages.Remove(pageToRemove);
```

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't find anymore.